# libstdc++.6.dylib not found when creating static library in xCode

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to rebuild an old app (still available on the store) to change some minor settings. I re-opened the project I didn't touch for a couple of years and when trying to build it I have the following error :

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file : /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.2.sdk/usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (No such file or Directory)`

I have this error building a static library used by the app. Any idea ?

Comment: Probably because the library that used to exist on a relative path to the sdk is no longer there.

Comment: Ok I feel dumb now. there was a ref of libstdc++.6.dylib in the project of the static lib. Looks like it builds fine now that I've just removed it (except from some signing issues) Thank Milan

Comment: @ChrisR. What the version of xCode do you use ? Please try to add the equivalent library with extension .tbd instead and clean and build , If you are still getting this error . Try to download the missing library and import it to your app . Nada Gamal

Comment: I had similar issue 'library not found for -lstdc++.6' while running ionic project using Xcode 10.1. I have removed libstdc++.6 from Xcode(General --> Linked Frameworks and Libraries) and build is successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I feel dumb now. there was a ref of libstdc++.6.dylib in the project of the static lib. Looks like it builds fine now that I've just removed it (except from some signing issues) Thank Milan